# building ntp without ntpdate

Tags: ntp, ntpdate

I would like to build ntp without ntpdate.

I configured the installation with this command: `--without-PACKAGE` and replaced `PACKAGE` with `ntpdate` as it is done with the option `--without-sntp`.

Somehow the ntpdate executable is still build.

Do you have any idea what causes this behaviour?

Regards Frogtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `ntpdate`  as `ntpd -q`  works for ntp4. And having the "to be retired" ntpdate around does not hurt anything.

If you really care about removing it, you are going to need to think like a package maintainer. Dig deeper into the configure script, or remove it at the end of your build.